# How many ligands in Heme?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

How many ligands does Fe has in heme ?
I am not sure how many are in heme and how many in cytochrome C.
Its about iron complexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heme:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heme) The Iron molecule is bound to 4 Nitrogen atoms, but take a look at [porphyrin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrin). All the nitrogens are part of one actual structure. You can visualize the iron molecule in the center of the larger compound's structure, replacing the two Hydrogen atoms in N-H:

The large structure surrounding and coordinating with Fe is also known as a **polydentate ligand** since it bonds to Iron at more than one site. So there is just one ligand on Fe.

[image: porphyrin]
[image]

Cytochrome C: is a heme protein, so you may expect the same answer: A single polydentate ligand binds to Iron. [This page](http://www.proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Cytochrome_c) has a PDB Model of it in a plugin.

As one ligand coordinates to four sites in this case, other ligands typically attach (e.g. oxygen binding in hemoglobin) to fill the octahedral group (up to 6 ligands attached to Fe the coordinate center).