# Why do nitrogen molecules not act as ligands in haemoglobin?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry, coordination-compounds

Nitrogen molecules $(\ce{N2})$ have lone pairs, which, as far as I know, is the property of oxygen molecules $(\ce{O2})$ that allows them to act as ligands bonding to iron in haemoglobin in the blood. Why then is atmospheric nitrogen unable to act as a ligand and form dative bonds to iron in the blood as oxygen is able to?

Comment: N2 is even worse as ligand then oxygen, its complexes are rare.

Comment: It can, at least at high pressure, see e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3417671

Comment: @Mithoron Okay, but *why* is N2 a worse ligand than O2?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118773/why-co-is-a-stronger-and-more-common-ligand-than-n2 I have a similar question but still no answer

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14434/how-many-ligands-in-heme/14448