# Why CO is a stronger and more common ligand than N2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, ligand-field-theory

Both N2 and CO are considered sigma-donor and pi-acceptor. Their MO diagram is similar, so I wonder why CO binds generally more strongly and it is a more common ligand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/93797/why-do-nitrogen-molecules-not-act-as-ligands-in-haemoglobin

Comment: Both the sigma HOMO and the pi LUMO of CO are polarised towards carbon - so the overlap with metal orbitals is much better

Comment: I saw the link and the other question doesn't have an answer jet. I saw they asked about N2 and O2, I think it is a different explanation because N2 and O2 have very different MO instead N2 and CO are very similar

Comment: @orthocresol - do you mean that is because CO is polar? (2 different atoms)

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzAyK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzAyK.png) The answer to the above question is attached.Read M.Tarr

Comment: Even though it is basically the reversed explanation, it might still be helpful: [How to rationalise with MO theory that CO is a two-electron donor through carbon?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51262/4945)